# Trying to access .properties file using spring server and cloud. Works on local repo but not in git remote repo

Tags: spring, spring-boot, github

I am working on microservices using springboot. While configuring the server, everything is going smoothly. I am working on springboot 2.4 with cloud version 2020.0.0.

1. enabled @EnableConfigServer on the main application class
2. added bootstrap dependency
3. created new git repo and property file
4. added configuration to the pom file

But when I work with a local git repo, my server responds and I can access the application through URL (eg. localhost:8888/client/default).

However, when I provide my remote git URL, the server does not respond to anything. My URL is correct and I have provided the username and passwords too.
There are no errors and nothing. Only 404 error page created by springboot.

What is the issue here? can anyone help?

POM::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.config</groupId>
<artifactId>server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>server</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Main Class::

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ServerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

application.properties::

```
spring.config.name= server
server.port= 8888

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/chiranjiviNeupane/MicroserviceRepo
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username= chiranjiviNeupane
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password= ********

spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start= true

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= *
```

But when I replace spring.cloud.config.server.git.url with local repo works fine. However, implementing a remote git address does not work. It doesn't give any errors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your git repository has `main` branch not `master` which is default branch for cloud config server.
To resolve this, you need to run client with property `-Dspring.cloud.config.label=main` or create `master` branch from `main` branch.

Comment: I renamed the branch to master and that worked. Thanks!